# logstash elasticsearch output not deleting documents

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-jdbc

I have the following config to get deleted entries from jdbc input and delete them from the ES index, I see that it runs and queries DB and gets entries but documents with those ids still exist in the index. What can be wrong here?

```
input {
  jdbc {
    statement => "SELECT id, ad FROM table WHERE last_updated > :sql_last_value AND date_deleted IS NOT NULL LIMIT :size OFFSET :offset"
    jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "${DB_URL}"
    jdbc_user => "${DB_USER}"
    jdbc_password => "${DB_PASSWORD}"
    jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/jar/jdbc/postgresql-42.2.5.jar"
    jdbc_page_size => 20000
    jdbc_paging_enabled => true
    jdbc_paging_mode => "explicit"
    last_run_metadata_path => "/usr/share/logstash/opt/lastruns/deleted_last_run"
    schedule => "*/15 * * * *"
    # ... other configuration bits
  }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "${ES_HOST}"
        index => "myindex"
        document_id => "%{id}"
        user => "elastic"
        password => "${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}"
        action => "delete"
    }
}
```

Both elastic search and logstash are version 8.0.0.

Comment: did you check logstash log file and confirm that there is no error logs available ?

Comment: also, what is version of Logstash and Elasticsearch.

Comment: can you please set `codec => json` in input and try it.

Comment: @SagarPatel they're version 8, I'll check your suggestions.

Comment: @SagarPatel logs to stdout (it runs in docker) show no error.

Comment: Did you tried codec json ?

Comment: @SagarPatel, no but I added some logs and verified the requests hit elastic search server. How would setting codec to json in input help?